# Unable to retrieve component configurator for plugin configuration / Artifact has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2

Tags: java, maven-2, javafx-2

I am trying to use  zonski's [`javafx-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/wiki), however when executing

```
mvn com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:1.2:fix-classpath
```

(more details on [Fixing the JRE classpath](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/wiki/Fixing-the-JRE-classpath)) I get one warning and one error:

```
[WARNING] While downloading org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
  This artifact has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2.
  https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-244

[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error configuring: com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin. Reason: Unable to retrieve component configurator for plugin configuration
```

Here's the full log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:1.5:fix-classpath] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] While downloading org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
  This artifact has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2.
  https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-244


-----------------------------------------------------
this realm = app0.child-container[com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:1.5]
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin/1.5/javafx-maven-plugin-1.5.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/twdata/maven/mojo-executor/2.0/mojo-executor-2.0.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-plexus/1.4.2/sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.2.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-api/1.7/aether-api-1.7.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/zenjava/javafx-deploy-lib/1.2/javafx-deploy-lib-1.2.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.1.1/plexus-archiver-2.1.1.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.3/plexus-io-2.0.3.jar
Number of imports: 10
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@a6c57a42
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@12f43f3b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@20025374
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@f8e44ca4
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@92758522
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@ebf2705b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bb25e54
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bece5185
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee8e37
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee19d8


this realm = plexus.core
urls[0] = file:/C:/maven/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/../lib/maven-2.2.1-uber.jar
Number of imports: 10
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@a6c57a42
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@12f43f3b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@20025374
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@f8e44ca4
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@92758522
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@ebf2705b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bb25e54
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bece5185
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee8e37
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee19d8
-----------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error configuring: com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin. Reason: Unable to retrieve component configurator for plugin configuration
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Apr 21 17:36:51 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/22M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any hints on how to fix this? Thanks :-)

Update: Using -e switch for maven:

```
C:\Users\myuser> mvn -e com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:1.5:fix-classpath
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:1.5:fix-classpath] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] While downloading org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
  This artifact has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2.
  https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-244


-----------------------------------------------------
this realm = app0.child-container[com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:1.5]
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin/1.5/javafx-maven-plugin-1.5.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/twdata/maven/mojo-executor/2.0/mojo-executor-2.0.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-plexus/1.4.2/sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.2.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-api/1.7/aether-api-1.7.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/com/zenjava/javafx-deploy-lib/1.2/javafx-deploy-lib-1.2.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.1.1/plexus-archiver-2.1.1.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.3/plexus-io-2.0.3.jar
Number of imports: 10
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@a6c57a42
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@12f43f3b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@20025374
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@f8e44ca4
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@92758522
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@ebf2705b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bb25e54
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bece5185
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee8e37
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee19d8


this realm = plexus.core
urls[0] = file:/C:/maven/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/../lib/maven-2.2.1-uber.jar
Number of imports: 10
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@a6c57a42
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@12f43f3b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@20025374
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@f8e44ca4
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@92758522
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@ebf2705b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bb25e54
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bece5185
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee8e37
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee19d8
-----------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error configuring: com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin. Reason: Unable to retrieve component configurator for plugin configuration
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error configuring: com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin. Reason: Unable to retrieve component confi
gurator for plugin configuration
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:723)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginConfigurationException: Error configuring: com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin. Reason: Unable to retrieve compon
ent configurator for plugin configuration
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultPluginManager.java:1368)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:724)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Unable to lookup component 'org.codehaus.plexus.component.conf
igurator.ComponentConfigurator', it could not be created
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:335)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultPluginManager.java:1351)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.ComponentInstantiationException: Could not instanciate component: role: 'org.codehaus.plexus.componen
t.configurator.ComponentConfigurator', implementation: 'org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator', role hint: 'basic'
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.java.JavaComponentFactory.makeException(JavaComponentFactory.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.java.JavaComponentFactory.newInstance(JavaComponentFactory.java:62)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.createComponentInstance(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1464)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.createComponentInstance(AbstractComponentManager.java:93)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.ClassicSingletonComponentManager.getComponent(ClassicSingletonComponentManager.java:92)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:331)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.java.JavaComponentFactory.newInstance(JavaComponentFactory.java:44)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 31 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Apr 21 17:52:00 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/22M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: hint: one should use latest version mvn com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:1.5:fix-classpath instead of mvn com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:1.2:fix-classpath

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding to the [From Zero To JavaFX In 5 Minutes](http://www.zenjava.com/2012/11/24/from-zero-to-javafx-in-5-minutes/), it mentions as the following: -

> Before starting you will need to have installed **JDK 7 update 6 or later**, and **Maven 3.0 or later**. [This guide](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-maven-and-how-do-i-install-it.html) will walk you through that.

Please correct me, if I'm wrong. I understand that you're using the `Maven 2.2.1`, please upgrade your `Maven` to be a `version 3.x`.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, I was using Maven 2 and with Maven 3 it works fine :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use the JavaFX integration with maven, using it as System Dependency? Maybe this approach can help you.

You can create the maven project as a default one. You need to define the JAVA_HOME environment variable where your JDK is installed (I'm assuming that you have one of the latest JDK with the JavaFX integrated on it) and add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javafx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Note that there is no need to use the environment variable, you can put a full path of your system [This is the link for Maven System dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)

And to execute your project, when you generate your project, you need to include this jar in your classpath.

```
java -cp path_to_jfxrt.jar:all_your_dependencies:your_generated.jar your_package.YourClass
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that I was using Maven 2 instead of Maven 3, though your post is nice for the archive / a manual way :-)